# How to replace overlayItem.getfocus() in Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

In Google maps v1 you know which focus overlayItem, with overlayItem.getfocus().

```
mPlaceOverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(icon, mMapView, this);
OverlayItem myFocusOverlayItem = null;
myFocusOverlayItem = mPlaceOverlay.getFocus();
```

But now in Google maps v2 I don't know which is the marker.I hope somebody of you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register marker click listener via [`GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnMarkerClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener%29) and whenever some marker clicked - you need to remember this marker. That's the way to get currently focused marker.

Obviously you might want to "clear" last focused marker when user "unclicks" this marker (taps on a map, etc). In this case you need to register [`onInfoWindowClickListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnInfoWindowClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener%29) and [`onMapClickListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnMapClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener%29) and clear last focused item when these events occur

Comment: But now, How to do overlayItem.setFocus() in Google maps v2?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in onCreate method...

```
  Marker pos = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("You are here!").title("You are here!"));
```